# Whether using dynamic cast for providing input for derived class virtual function is recommended?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, dynamic-cast

I read some of the answers in [What is the proper use case for dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776777/what-is-the-proper-use-case-for-dynamic-cast).

The line which best matched my situation here is

```
#include<iostream>

class Shape
{
   public:
      virtual void draw()=0;
      virtual ~Shape(){};
};

class  Rectangle : public Shape
{
   public:
      int length;
      int breath;

      void draw()
      {
         std::cout<<"RECTANGE"<<std::endl;
      }

};


class  Circle : public Shape
{
   public:
      int diameter;

      void draw()
      {
         std::cout<<"CIRCLE"<<std::endl;
      }

};


/*Abstract Factory*/

Shape* getShapeObj(int type)
{
   switch(type)
   {
      case 1:
         return new Rectangle;

      case 2:
         return new Circle;

         /*  many types will be added here in future. */
   }

   return NULL;
};

void drawShapes(Shape *p_shape[],int len)
{
   for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
      p_shape[i]->draw();
}

int main()
{
   Shape *l_shape[2];
   l_shape[0]=getShapeObj(1);
   l_shape[1]=getShapeObj(2);
   Rectangle *l_rec=dynamic_cast<Rectangle*>(l_shape[0]);

   if(l_rec)
   {
      l_rec->length=10;
      l_rec->breath=20;
   }

   Circle *l_circle=dynamic_cast<Circle*>(l_shape[1]);

   if(l_circle)
      l_circle->diameter=25;

   drawShapes(l_shape,2);

}
```

> *Essentially, virtual functions only work in some cases, not all of them.*

My problem is to pass the input for the virtual function and inputs will vary from type to type. Whether using dynamic cast is recommended here?

Comment: *"to pass the input for the virtual function and inputs will vary from type to type"* - I don't see a place in your code where you use a virtual functions with some inputs... Could you elaborate? You cannot override a virtual function and change its parameters...

Comment: What does the above code achieve that `Rectangle *l_rec = new Rectangle(10, 20);` does not achieve?  (Or even better `auto l_rec = std::make_unique<Rectangle>(10,20);`).  I understand this is a simplified example, but I don't see what the complex example would look like.

Comment: @Holt  updated the code with elaborated example

Comment: @VinothKumar Thanks. What is the real purpose of this `getShapeObj` function?  Why can't you simply do e.g. `l_shape[0] = new Rectangle(10, 2);` (after having created a corresponding constructor)?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is perfect forwarding of function parameters, introduced in c++11.

```
template<typename ...CtorArgs>
Shape* getShapeObj(int type, CtorArgs&& ctor_args...)
{
   switch(type)
   {
      case 1:
         return new Rectangle(std::forward<CtorArgs>(ctor_args)...);
     // many types will be added here in future.
   }

    return NULL;
}
```

Obviously making the function a template, defeats the purpose of hiding the hierarchy (as well as forcing rather strict requirements on the number of parameters to the constructors). But if the base contains a map of functions that do the construction, which each derived class updates with a pointer to function that constructs it, you can still have information hiding.

---

I have recently written an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41103048/817643) about storing type erased function pointers in a map, with some static type checking forwarded to run time.

Comment: This will only works if all subclasses have the same constructor parameters since the whole function body need to well-formed.

Comment: @Holt - Yes. Braking it apart to accommodate different c'tor parameters will require a level of indirection, say via tag dispatch. But the point is that there are ways to avoid a `dynamic_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, looks like your `main` function is taking too much responsibility. What if you have `Circle`, `Hexagon`, `MyFancyFigure` types? All of them should be initialized in `main` in different branches?

It would be much better to move that "initialization" logic to a separate virtual function `init` in your classes (or even to the constructor). The code would look like this:

```
class Shape
{
   public:
      virtual void draw()=0;
      virtual void init()=0;
      virtual ~Shape(){};
};

class  Rectangle : public Shape
{
   public:
      int length;
      int breath;

      void draw()
      {
         //Draw Rectangle
      }

      void init()
      {
         length = 10;
         breath = 20;
      }
};

int main()
{
   Shape *l_shape=getShapeObj(1);
   // Calls different code of "init" method depending on the actual object type
   l_shape->init();
   l_shape->draw();
   delete l_shape;
}
```

Also, please note that this initialization logic may be place in some other place, like constructor of the class or the factory method. But `main` is definitely the wrong place.

Comment: @alexykuzmin My input will vary depend on type. Mean to say you have hardcoded the input in init.

Comment: @VinothKumar If it depends on type, you probably have now more than one if in `main` function. This code will look much better when distributed between multiple `init` functions of derived classes. I hope I understood you correctly.